# How to create custom user using the REST API?

Tags: graphdb

I am using GraphDB free edition.

I wanted to create a user via REST API and found in the documentation that  `/rest/security/user/**` could be used to create a user.

But what is `**` in api endpoint and also how to create a user using the above endpoint? What should be the parameters and body for the POST request?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create user using GraphDB REST API using following cURL request:

```
     curl 'http://localhost:7201/rest/security/user/username' -H 'Origin: 
    http://localhost:7201' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:7201/user/create' -H 'X-GraphDB-Repository: 
repository name' -H 'X-GraphDB-Password: user password' -H 'DNT: 1' --data-binary '{"appSettings": 
{"DEFAULT_SAMEAS":true,"DEFAULT_INFERENCE":true,"EXECUTE_COUNT":true,"IGNORE_SHARED_QUERIES":false},"grantedAuthorities":
["ROLE_USER","WRITE_REPO_*","READ_REPO_*"]}' --compressed
```

Comment: The user is created when security is off, how to create when security is on? Like only admin can create users?

Comment: @Shiva yes, only admin users can create other users. You can pass the credentials with the curl request by adding "-u admin:root"

Answer (score 0):

You should add -u admin username:password or send for example http://localhost:port number/rest/login POST request with "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8", "Accept", "application/json" with JSONObject with registered admin user - username and password and will get header "Authorization" as result token generated for user and you should attach it like: 'Authorization: returned authorization header'.